# Split video into equal file size parts with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

i am trying to split a video file into equal file size parts with ffmpeg.

At first i get the file size of the original and divide it with the desired number of parts to get the file part's file size.

Then i try to do something like :

ffmpeg.exe -y -i video.mp4 -fs 1000000 video-part1.mp4
ffmpeg.exe -y -i video.mp4 -ss [LAST_VIDEO_PART_DURATION] -fs 1000000 video-part2.mp4

but i do not get satisfying results because the -fs does not work as it is required.

The part file sizes become not the same.

Anyone who has a solution for this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can I ask why you need this?

Comment: i am making an application to split video files.

Comment: Fair enough, but why would someone need this? I mean, normally you split on time, not on file size. Also, you cannot exactly guarantee a specific file size as output—it'll always be a little inaccurate. Anyway, your question lacks details. Please include the full command line output too, and tell us what the actual file size is that you're getting. (Not just "not the same")